# How to print previous/multiple lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
key = int(input("Choose a Christmas Gift from 1 to 5!"))
 if type(key) != type(0):
  print("Please enter a number.")
  exit()
 if not (1 <= key <= 5):
  print(key,"is an invalid number.")
  exit()

if key == 1:
 print("1 Partridge in a Pear Tree.")
elif key == 2:
 print("2 Turtle Doves.")
elif key == 3:
 print("3 French Hens.")
elif key == 4:
 print("4 Calling Birds.")
elif key == 5:
 print("5 Golden Rings.")
```

I got this far (I am very new to this and I did what I saw in class), but I don't know how to print the previous lines when you input a number.

Say I enter 3.

Output should be:

```
3 french hens.
2 turtle doves
1 partridge in a pear tree.
```

And it should do that for all valid numbers.

Edit: I changed the eval to int.

Any advice helps! Thank you.

Comment: If you want integers, please don't do `eval(input(...))`. That's just asking for a typo to break your code in unintentional ways. `int(input(...))` would make valid inputs work, and raise predictable `ValueError`s for invalid inputs, no need for `eval`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Oh okay thank you, I will go fix that whoops! I still need help with printing the other lines.

Comment: @ShadowRanger This makes so much more sense. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse your tests, make them based on `>=`, not `==`, and don't use `elif` (which makes the first test that passes prevent any others from executing), just plain `if`. Now every test that passes prints in order as you go.

```
if key >= 5:
    print("5 Golden Rings.")
if key >= 4:
    print("4 Calling Birds.")
if key >= 3:
    print("3 French Hens.")
if key >= 2:
    print("2 Turtle Doves.")
if key >= 1:
    print("1 Partridge in a Pear Tree.")
```

Comment: Okay okay got it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

What I did was reverse them so they print from greatest to least and made == to >= to print it if it was greater than that number.

```
from sys import exit
key = int(input("Choose a Christmas Gift from 1 to 5!"))
if type(key) != type(0):
    print("Please enter a number.")
    exit()
if not (1 <= key <= 5):
    print(key,"is an invalid number.")
    exit()

if key >= 5:
    print("5 Golden Rings.")
if key >= 4:
    print("4 Calling Birds.")
if key >= 3:
    print("3 French Hens.")
if key >= 2:
    print("2 Turtle Doves.")
if key >= 1:
    print("1 Partridge in a Pear Tree.")
```

However if you want to expand this do the following:

```
from sys import exit
    key = int(input("Choose a Christmas Gift from 1 to 5!"))
    if type(key) != type(0):
        print("Please enter a number.")
        exit()
    if not (1 <= key <= 5):
        print(key,"is an invalid number.")
        exit()
gifts = ["1 partridge in a pair tree","2 turtle doves","etc..","etc..","etc.."]
printer = [print (val) for ind,val in enumerate (gifts) if ind >=key]
```

the printer works by using list comprehension which is the same thing as saying

```
for ind,val in enumerate(gifts):
   if ind >= key:
      print(val)
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! It's clear what I did wrong now. This makes a lot more sense than what my TA attempted to teach us -_-

Comment: I'm in favor of the refactoring, but don't use list comprehensions for side-effects (like `print`ing). That just means making temporary `list`s full of `None` for no reason, when a plain loop `for ind, val in enumerate(gifts):` `if ind >= key: print(val)` would do the job just fine. Beyond the temporary, any use of functional programming tools (e.g. listcomps) for side-effects is a maintenance nightmare; functional styles are intended to minimize side-effects and action at a distance.

Comment: Oh snap, I can imagine how tedious it can be! Thanks for the advice. I will be keeping that in mind for future assignments! This one was given to me without context or clear instructions. :D